# Write a DVD from the Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, dvd, burning

Does anyone know an easy way to write files to a DVD from the command line. I've found a program that does it for CDs, and another that writes .ISO images to DVD.

I want to use it to write files to a backup DVD overnight.

Answer (score 1):

From this fairly old blog post [here](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2006/08/burn-dvds-from-windows-command-line.htm) you can have a look at dvdburn.exe which is part of the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en). It is not tied to the OS specifically so you could extract it to your machine and just run it from the command line.

Various links and blog posts reveals that it does work under Windows Vista and 7 althought it is only targetted and Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

You will however need to create the ISO first. You will need an application like [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/tutorials.htm) which has a command line tool that allows for the creation of an ISO images before writing it to DVD. However this is not a free tool. You can look at [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) which is free and does also offer a commandline component, however it is not very well documented.

Comment: Doesn't that only burn ISO images though? I need to burn a directory full of files.

Comment: @Simon - Updated my answer.

Comment: ISO images can be created with the command-line tools `mkisofs` or `genisoimage`.  these are available via Cygwin; there seem to be native win32 `mkisofs` binaries floating around in various places too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Nero it comes with a command line app Nerocmd.exe, you use the --dvd parameter for dvd iso's.