# Is it possible to burn an iso image to a DVD using cmd in Windows 7 or 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, command-line, burning

Is that possible to burn an `.iso` file to a DVD using command prompt in Windows 7 or 8?

If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Write a DVD from the Windows Command Line](http://superuser.com/questions/110823/write-a-dvd-from-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: But the original question's answer doesn't explains how to burn iso images to DVD via cmd,it lists only the tools available. And also if I burn The iso file using the below answer ,does it make the DVD to bootable?

Comment: `But the original question's answer doesn't explains how to burn iso images to DVD via cmd,it lists only the tools available.` Then read the tools’ documentations and/or use their help-switches to find out their syntax. Alternately, add a comment and/or bounty to that question; no reason to re-ask the same question. `if I burn The iso file using the below answer ,does it make the DVD to bootable?` If you burn a bootable `.iso` file using any method, then it will be bootable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is possible to burn iso files from the windows command line, however only in Windows 7 and above.

## How to Burn an Image from the Command Line in Windows

ISO or IMG image files can be burned in both Windows 7 or 8 from the command line quite easily. First, open the Command Prompt and then type isoburn to get the following guick syntax guide. As has been noted in the discussion below, you don't need to reference.exe since it lives in the system32 folder.

[image]

Start isoburn.exe using the following command and parameters:

**Syntax:**

```
isoburn.exe /q [the CD/DVD writing drive]
```

**Example:**

```
isoburn.exe /q D: C:\Users\JDoe\Desktop\image.iso
```

[image]

After a few moments, you'll see:

[image]

While yes, the process can be fired up from the command line, this window may still need to be closed by hand.

**See Also:**

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/The-Complete-Guide-to-Burning-Disk-Images-(ISO-&-IMG)-In-Windows-7/71219

Comment: Does the DVD bootable?

Comment: if the iso was created as a bootable image, then yeah, but if it's just files, no. it just depends how the iSO was compiled.

Answer (score 4):

```
isoburn /q <drive letter>: <disc image>
```

that should work.

Comment: isoburn.exe or only isoburn ?

Comment: you can use either, since they refer to the same program.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - You will need to provide the full path to the installation directory of isoburn the file extension is optional in a case like this.

Comment: <disc image> means path to the image file?

Comment: isoburn.exe is located in C:\windows\system32, so you can run it in any folder without the full path. I suggest going to the folder where you hold the image file and do isoburn /q d: "image name.iso"

Comment: isoBurn is not a system utility you sure it's in a the System32 system folder?

Comment: I've confirmed it on Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a standard part of Windows since Vista. 2008 and 2012 server have it too.

Comment: The only IsoBurn I find is a portable application...wierd

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), which has great command line support and tons of extra options (too many to list here) over the built in `isoburn.exe`.